# How to compute correlation between all variables?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, correlation

I cleaned previously my dataset and I am trying to compute correlation between some variables from my csv files.
This is all of my columns :

```
Index(['ID', 'age', 'sex', 'city', 'province', 'country', 'latitude',
       'longitude', 'geo_resolution', 'date_onset_symptoms',
       'date_admission_hospital', 'date_confirmation', 'symptoms',
       'lives_in_Wuhan', 'travel_history_dates', 'travel_history_location',
       'reported_market_exposure', 'additional_information',
       'chronic_disease_binary', 'chronic_disease', 'source',
       'sequence_available', 'outcome', 'date_death_or_discharge',
       'notes_for_discussion', 'location', 'admin3', 'admin2', 'admin1',
       'country_new', 'admin_id', 'data_moderator_initials',
       'travel_history_binary'],
      dtype='object')
```

- I computed correlation by doing df.corr and I had this output :

```
                        latitude  longitude  chronic_disease_binary  admin_id
latitude                1.000000   0.180020               -0.027188  0.172725
longitude               0.180020   1.000000                0.016198  0.242909
chronic_disease_binary -0.027188   0.016198                1.000000 -0.007604
admin_id                0.172725   0.242909               -0.007604  1.000000
```

I tried to compute correlation between sex and latitude to understand why I cannot have all columns and I have casting error :

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

How can I compute correlation between all variables ?

Comment: One of the columns is of string type. You can't correlate string and integer type features.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are some columns filled by string repr of numbers.

You can use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) for all columns for convert non numeric to missing values and then remove only `NaN`s columns:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).dropna(how='all', axis=1).corr()
```

Or if necesary specify columns in list for processing:

```
cols = ['age','latitude','longitude']
df = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).corr()
```